# Get value from registry C++ crashes

Tags: c++, winapi

What's wrong? It crashes when I want to get value of AUVersion. This key exists in registry but I can't get it.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    HKEY key;
    if (RegOpenKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("SOFTWARE\\JavaSoft\\Auto Update\\"), &key) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout << "Unable to open registry key\n\n";
    }

    char path[1024];
    DWORD value_length = 1024;
//here is the crash
    RegQueryValueEx(key, "AUVersion", NULL, (LPDWORD)REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)&path, &value_length);
    cout << "the value read from the registry is: " << path << endl;


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

That fourth parameter is an `LPDWORD` -- a pointer to a DWORD. You took a regular integer and cast it to a pointer, which (when dereferenced) will crash.

That parameter *receives* the type of the registry value. Set it to NULL if you are not interested in knowing the type.

Comment: @user1857483 if this is the answer, you should accept it. Click the green check box by this answer.

Answer (score 4):

There are two errors with the call to [`RegQueryValueEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms724911%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

- the type parameter is written to so must be a valid address, and this is not:

  ```
  (LPDWORD)REG_SZ
  ```

and this is the probable cause of the crash.

- `&path` should be `path`

Change to:

```
DWORD type;
RegQueryValueEx(key, "AUVersion", NULL, &type, (LPBYTE) path, &value_length);
```

You must check the result of `RegQueryValueEx()` to ensure `path` has been populated and subsequent code is not processing an unitialized variable:

```
const DWORD result = RegQueryValueEx(key,
                                     "AUVersion",
                                     NULL,
                                     &type,
                                     (LPBYTE) path,
                                     &value_length);

// Check status of the query and ensure it was a string
// that was read.
if (ERROR_SUCCESS == result && REG_SZ == type)
{
    // Success.
}
```

Comment: @nneonneo, noticed that. The only thing I have omitted is that it must be the ASCII version of `RegQueryValueEx()`.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I was just looking at the MSDN documentation and apparently you should check if ERROR_MORE_DATA, since your buffer could be initially too small

Comment: @0A0D, my example code states that the user must check the return value. The OP should read the documentation and handle that.